# Dynamically adding data from multiple tables into a single one in Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers, spreadsheet, apple-numbers

I have multiple tables in a single spreadsheet in Apple Numbers. I want to have a single, master table in another spreadsheet that contains all the data from these tables and that grows automatically as I keep adding more rows to them.

For example:

Input Table 1:

```
| Header 1 | Header 2
|    A     |    B
```

Input Table 2:

```
| Header 1 | Header 2
|    C     |    D
```

Master Table:

```
| Header 1 | Header 2
|    A     |    B
|    C     |    D
```

And as I keep adding data rows to Table 1 and Table 2, I want the Master Table to automatically reflect them as well. Is this possible in Apple Numbers, and if so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: I came here looking for a very similar solution: 

I want to automagically populate a “Shopping List” table with the “Ingredient” name whose “Need It?” checkbox is checked/true. 

So, check the box and the Ingredient gets added to the Shopping list. Uncheck it and it removes. 

The part that’s throwing me —if it can even be done— is how to generate a dynamic Shopping List table. I kind of don’t think it’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a summary table and populate rows using something like this:

```
IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT($A11&" "&$B11&"::S")),"")
```